# using SET datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a varaible to a query result such as:

```
DECLARE result INT;

SET result = (SELECT index FROM table WHERE data = 'xxxx' LIMIT 1);
```

Assuming of course you know that there will only be one result set

Answer (score 1):

only within a procedure.